# Azure Function triggered by queue concurrency

Tags: stored-procedures, concurrency, azure-functions, message-queue

I have an azure function which calls a stored procedure from the azure database. it works in a way that when it gets the message "A" it should copy file "A" from blob storage into temporary table "A" in the database by using BULK INSERT .csv files and I might get several files in one second that needs to be inserted into separated tables.

The problem is that when I manually add one and only one message in the queue using "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer" to trigger the function it works perfectly fine and I can see the data in the destination table but when it is running automatically it has to deal with more than only one file. So none of the tables have any data and none of the files are copied! AND NO EXCEPTION! weird!

So does anyone know how it works when we call several azure functions concurrently especially when they have database transactions by calling same stored procedure which works with different sources and targets?

Comment: I feel like having multiple threads trying to run the same stored procedure that accesses similar tables is not an ideal use case if you can avoid it. Is there any way you can simply have a single thread, like a webjob, read the queue and only run the stored procedure again once the last execution has finished?

Comment: @Slothario I was trying to reach a file which did not even exist since It was the copy process which was running

Comment: You probably should verify whether or not you need concurrent database uploads, because multiple jobs trying to access the database at once under heavy load would just put unnecessary strain on it. It definitely seems like the jobs should be sequential -- think about it, if you get slammed with 100 jobs, should they all try to run at once? However, if there really is a use case for it, or you can't rewrite that code no matter how badly you want to, you're going to have to do more research to find out what's going on because I can't tell you what's happening from the description.

Comment: @Slothario can you take a look at this one? this is another question that i have:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59176671/blob-trigger-azure-function-execution

Answer (score 0):

The related queue to this function is being filled by another azure function which copies files from FileShare into BlobStorage and since this process is an Async one, Then first azure function copies file and before the copying finishes, it executes the rest of the code which contains adding messages to the second queue and run the second function when the file size is 0KB